# ASP.NET mvc 2 Validation always shows errors on initial page load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I've searched around a lot, and honed this problem down to this case:
I'm using the PRG pattern, pragmatically I'm using the same DTO for my post/get actions. It looks like when I have the dto with the data annotation attributes in the get action parameter list, the validation is always displaying errors, every time on initial page load.

In some cases this could be desired behavior if you put asterisks in the error message, but how do I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem and solution also apply to MVC 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to clear your modelstate with a call to modelstate.clear() in your action.